# iFrame not available - Why?

Tags: html, facebook, iframe

So I have a website and I want to view the most recent posts on my website, this, I was told, could be done by using a Facebook Like-Box, I got down to it and did all that I needed, filled in the url and everything, the preview even showed the rite page as well as the latest post.

My problem is this: when I click on get code and then on the "iFrame" option, it is blank and I cannot seem to get this working for me, did they disable the iFrame option or what is going on?

I really want to use that specific route(iFrame), not HTML5 or any other way.

I tried using the default iFrame code as follows, only editing it to the page I want to embed:

The page is located at : https://www.facebook.com/pages/XXXXX/XXXXX
This however did not work. I just showed a blank page.

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: I would love to, but that is just the thing, Facebook doesn't give me the iFrame code, I tried manually editing the code most people posted like follows:<iframe style="overflow:hidden;border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:315px;" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FLasting-Roses%2F619091368103718%2&width=450&height=315&show_faces=false&colorscheme=light&stream=true&border_color&header=false&appId=397375460320824">
</iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

iframe code in my case, change with your page

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FPillole-di-programmazione%2F447183265411478&amp;width&amp;height=590&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=true&amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code, worked like a charm, did not use https, used http and also had a typo on closing the URL at the end you had one more "&" than I used, that fixed it, strange though that FB wouldn't give me the iFrame option, but thanx a million.

Comment: if you work often with fb you realize that changes very often the code. ;)